# Error when running a FetchRequest (Core Data, SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

While using Core Data together with SwiftUI, I have the following code compiling with no issue:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: MyEntity.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyEntity.name, ascending: true)]
) var myList: FetchedResults<MyEntity>

......

func wonderFunctio() {
    let theName = "Donald-Duck"
    print(#function)
    ......
    print("myList = \(myList.count)")
    
    let predic = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", theName)
    if FetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entity: MyEntity.entity(),
                                          sortDescriptors: [],
                                          predicate: predic)
        .wrappedValue.count != 0 {
        print("Useful message ....")
    }
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem when running. I get this error, in the *if FetchRequest* line.

```
  Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1eceee678)
```

Is there anything in my code that might seem unappropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entity...` is a property wrapper, so I assume it is invalid usage for it.

Here is a possible solution by using CoreData `NSFetchRequest` directly, which seems more appropriate way for use in function

```
let theName = "Donald-Duck"
let request: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", theName)

if let result = try? self.context.count(for: request), result != 0 {
    // .. do anything needed
}
```